# Is shipping included? (missing modifier, serial comma usage)

Tags: commas, modifiers

I'm not sure if there is a clear answer to this.  Is the "collect & return delivery cost" included in the $15 fee or is it impossible to tell?  Could it be fixed with a serial comma?

"All unsuccessful repairs are refunded minus a $15.00 fee for the engineer's time and the collect & return delivery cost."

Comment: Don’t use an ampersand. Spell it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language is ambiguous. It could mean

> All unsuccessful repairs are refunded minus a $15.00 fee (for the engineer's time and the collect & return delivery cost)

or it could mean

> All unsuccessful repairs are refunded minus a $15.00 fee (for the engineer's time) and [an additional fee deducted for] the collect & return delivery cost

An inquiry is needed to be sure.